# Is it possible to redirect the Magento 2 Contact Form without a custom module?

Tags: magento2, contact-us, redirect-url

I'm trying to get the Magento 2 Contact form to redirect not to /contact/index but someplace else.
Here is what I have so far:

We use a custom theme, in which I have created a the following folders

`Magento_Contact
    -email
        -submitted_form.html
    -templates
        - form.phtml`

I've edited the form.phtml to add / edit the fields as required.

I've created a content block and added the form to it with:

```
{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}
```

And I've created a CMS Page with this block in it, using

```
{{block class="Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block" block_id="myContact"}}
```

Now I want to the user to stay on that CMS Page after submitting the form, so I presume I will need to change `$this->_redirect('contact/index');` to `$this->_redirect('*/*/');` in the modules post controller.

I was wondering if there wasn't a quicker way to add the redirect, maybe as a block comment or similar.

Thank you.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No, I simply created a cms page under 'contact/index' with a 'Thank you and success message' and then redirected the user back to the form page using a very hacky cms block containing a meta refresh ... Now I would use a plugin with an after action, but this is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 4):

Old question but I found this through search.
@Design was 90% correct but apparently didn't test their answer.

First copy the Magento_Contact `form.phtml` to your theme.

> app/design/frontend/{Namespace}/{Theme}/Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml

Next, **append** the following script to the new file

```
<script>
require(
    ['jquery'],
    function($) {
        $('#contact-form').on('submit',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = this;
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormAction(); ?>",
                method : "POST",
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function(){ 
                    window.location = '/redirect';
                },
                error: function(){ 
                    console.error("Some error occurred, make sure Contact Form is enabled in Magento.");
                }
            });

        });
    }
);
</script>
```

Change `'/redirect'` to your desired redirect target.
You can also just replace the form with a success message. Here's a simple example of what I needed:

```
success: function(){ 
    form.outerHTML = "Thank you for contacting us, we will be in touch shortly!";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this one and it's working as clear as the water from my end.

Answer (score 4):

You can implement Magento 2 [after method plugin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#after-methods) for [execute method](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Contact/Controller/Index/Post.php#L25) of Post controller of Contact module. And create CMS page with 'contact/thanks' URL and redirect to the page in your plugin.
But in that case you need custom module to place your plugin.

```
<?php

namespace YourModule\ContactUsRedirect\Plugin;

class PostPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface
     */
    private $_dataPersistor;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface
     */
    private $_redirect;

    /**
     * PostPlugin constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect
    ) {
        $this->_dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        $this->_redirect = $redirect;
    }

    public function afterExecute(\Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post $subject, $result)
    {
        $post = $subject->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        if (!$post) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$this->_dataPersistor->get('contact_us')) {
            $this->_redirect->redirect($subject->getResponse(), 'contact/thanks');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by creating a permanent redirect in Marketing -> URL Rewrites from contact/index to my custom URL. It works and even shows the successful message.

Answer (score -1):

Make the form asynchronous and ignore the default action: (example in JQuery because it's bundled with M2.)

```
$('.form.contact').on('submit',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url:"<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormAction(); ?>",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(){ // it worked },
    error: function(){ // didn't work, why didn't he test his example before posting on SO?? }
  });

});
```